# Apache Hudi commit id for current ingestion

Tags: apache-spark, apache-hudi

How to get the current ingestion commit Id .I know HoodieDataSourceHelpers.latestCommit method can use to find the latest commit. But what happen if there is concurrent write in different thread. i need to find each thread commitID

Comment: you would post the question to hudi github issues or dev@hudi.apache.org ML.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HUDI-944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hudi does not allow concurrent writing at the moment. In any case `HoodieDataSourceHelpers.latestCommit` will return the latest commit always.